# Overlapping category axis label text in c3js charts

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, c3.js

If category axis label text is long or multiple words in a c3js chart, they are overlapping and makes it unreadable, is there any config or hack to fix this issue?

[image: c3js category axis label text overlapping]

[c3js category axis example](http://c3js.org/samples/categorized.html)

Copy and paste following code to reproduce this bug.

```
var chart = c3.generate({
  data: {
    columns: [
        ['data1',40, 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250, 50, 100, 250,67,190,48,123,76,54,254]
    ]
  },
  axis: {
    rotated: true,
    x: {
        type: 'category',
        categories: ['Travel and Hospitality','Life Science and Pharma', 'Saas and Cloud', 'Hi-tech Manufacturing', 'Software', 'Business Services', 'Govt/Public Sector', 'Energy', 'Manufacturing', 'Healthcare','Media','Internet','Retail','Biotech','Automobile','Consumer Goods','Financial Services']
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the height and top margin of the graph?

Comment: Yes, margin doesn't have any visible change on the chart, but by setting padding there is some changes, but overlap issue still persists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution in the 'multiline' config under axis_x_tick as shown below:-

```
axis: {
    rotated: true,
    x: {
        tick: {
            multiline: false,
        },
        type: 'category',
    }
 }
```

[Working example- multiline axis label disabled](http://jsfiddle.net/chetanbh/1nLn0xjn/)